# Laravel / Cartalyst Sentinel Authentication not detecting the user as logged in

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, cartalyst-sentinel

I'm on Laravel 5.1 using [Cartalyst's Sentinel](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0) as my authentication system. I'm using angular on my front-end.

I have a form at `domain.com/login` that sends a POST request to `api.domain.com/login`. If the user has entered correct credentials `api.domain.com/login` returns `{'success': true}` which my front-end looks at and eventually forwards to `domain.com/dashboard`

This is where the problem arises. The relevant portion of my dashboard controller:

```
if( Sentinel::check() ) {
    return view('dashboard');            
} else {

    return redirect()->route('login');
}
```

is not detecting the user as logged in. And keeps sending me back to `domain.com/login`

I suspect this is happening because the logging in part is happening at `api.domain.com` and we're checking to see if the user is logged in at `domain.com` and the browser isn't sending the relevant sentinel cookies. The [Sentinel docs](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0) doesn't mention anything about this.

If my suspicions are correct how can I allow Sentinel authenticate a user for both `api.domain.com` and `domain.com`? If my suspicions aren't correct, what is happening here?

Comment: Sentinel should be using Laravel's Cookie jar here, and so if your `session.cookie` config property is set properly, it should be picking it up. What does your console say about the cookie's domain?

Comment: In `config/session.php` I've changed `'domain' => null` to `'domain' => '.domain.com'` but still no luck

Comment: `null` *should* be the correct setting for multi-domain. If I'm not mistaken, the normal authentication driver handles this correctly. As such, perhaps it is worth opening an issue over at Sentinel's GH repo.